# 'a' with non count noun?

Tags: articles

From PEU/talking about the future:

> There are several ways to use verbs to talk about the future in
>   English. This is *a* complicated area of grammar.

I can't get the point of the indefinite article here? I thought *complicated area* is non count noun, therefore we shouldn't use 'a' the least, because we never use 'a' with non count noun. What's wrong?

Comment: Why do you think *area* is non-count? This triangle has a larger area than that triangle, but their areas are measured by the same formula hw/2. My friend Chuck and I live in different areas of the city. Some areas of the state are more salubrious than others. We're close to finalizing the contract, but there's still an area of disagreement.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different areas of grammar, and indeed many different *complicated* areas of grammar.

*One* of those many complicated areas of grammar is the ways to use verbs to talk about the future.